# How to programmatically check if an application has deployed in JBoss5?

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x, ear

I am writing a small app to automate deployments.  Basically, it checks an ftp server periodically for a new .ear file.  Compares the checksum of the remote ftp file against what is currently deployed.  If there is a new ftp file, then it gets picked up and deployed...

I then have a check to see if the app has deployed successfully.  At the moment, I am sending an http get requested for the main landing page of the app and then checking the http return code for a successful deployment.  However, I dont think this is the best way to check for a successful deployment as the serverside components might not have deployed.

Is there any way I could access some JBoss API to get a list of deployed applications?  Or, if anyone has any other ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss supports the [JSR-88 Deployment API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=88). Have a look at [this client](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JSR88Client) that deploys on JBoss using the JBoss JSR-88 implementation.

Comment: The JBoss Wiki link returns article not found.  Perhaps this is what you meant: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JSR88Client

Comment: @braveterry Yes, this is the page I was referring to (the previous link is dead due to the migration to the JBoss Community Portal). Thanks for pointing this out.