# Automatically build and deploy a Java Web Application

Tags: java, deployment, build, jboss, visual-sourcesafe

I am looking for a tool to build and deploy java web applications. Currently I am using JBOSS 4.x. The tool should be able to get the latest version from Visual Source Safe and make a build with latest code and deploy it to JBOSS application server.

Answer (score 1):

Ant has [WAR Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) to build WAR.

And to deploy,

- you should be invoking the JBoss Deploy MBean to deploy the built WAR Application.
- Or, copy the war to `JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy` directory which will automatically deploy the application.
- [Look here for different ways to deploy application in JBoss remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352900/jboss-remote-deployments)

Answer (score 1):

Maven is also a very widely used solution: http://maven.apache.org/

EDIT (Mulmoth):
To make the answer complete:
With its plugin architecture, it has appropriate support for [Visual Source Safe](http://maven.apache.org/scm/vss.html) and [JBoss](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Besides that, it has a lot of other blessings, like dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use Hudson.. Very good freeware deployment tool. [See more](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Home)